# mySQL form input, insert by looping, not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to StackOverflow, and relatively new to PHP.  I have a mixture of a mySQL table and form input, where a user will enter numbers into a field (options) next to each corresponding record (companyid), then submit and these should be inserted into the mySQL table.  If no "options" are entered, the loop should skip and move on.

When I submit, nothing is actually inserted into the database.  I need a little help because I have looked at several examples and I thought I had everything correct.

Thank you so much!!

Below is the table with form inputs:

```
<?php
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM company_main");

echo "<form action='userinvestdynamic.php' method='post'>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<table border=1>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>Company ID</td>";
   echo "<td>" .$row['company_id'] . "</td>";
   echo "<input type=hidden name=companyid[] value=" . $row['company_id'] . " />";
   echo "<td><input type=number name=options[]></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</table>";
   }
echo "<input name='userinvestoptionsdynamic' type='submit' value='Invest!'>";
echo "</form>";

 ?>
```

And here is the code once the form is submitted.

```
<?php
require ('db_login.php'); 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['userinvestoptionsdynamic'])) {

   $userid = $_SESSION['login_user'];
   $companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
   $options = $_POST['options'];

// loop through array
$number = count($_POST['companyid']);
for ($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
{
    //store single company and options in local variables
    $companyid = $companyid[$i];
    $options = $options[$i];

    //run insert for any items that don't have blank options
    if($options[$i] <>''){               

    $query = "INSERT INTO user_company_invested(user_id, company_id, user_company_options_invested) VALUES($userid,$companyid,$options)";

    mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }
}

header('Location: userpage.php');


} else {
   echo 'error';
}

?>
```

Comment: It's not working because your `$userid = $_SESSION['login_user'];` value `$userid` is based on a session variables, where it should be POST variable. Change it to `$userid = $_POST['login_user'];` --- When one value fails, the whole query fails.

Comment: add error-reporting to your `mysqli_query()` function (ie. `$return = mysqli_query(); if($return === false) { echo mysqli_error($connection); }`) so you can catch any errors and know why the query was not executed.

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- I actually specified the login user in the first page, and wanted to keep it from the session, not the form -- question was answered thanks again for the help though.

Comment: thanks @Tularis the answer below helped, I definitely need to work on error-reporting though.  thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanations are inside the comment /* */

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM company_main");

$counter=0; /* DECLARE THIS BEFORE YOUR WHILE LOOP */

echo "<form action='userinvestdynamic.php' method='post'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Company ID</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['company_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=companyid[$counter] value=" . $row['company_id'] . " />"; /* DECLARE THE COUNTER ON COMPANY ID ARRAY */
echo "<td><input type=number name=options[$counter]></td>"; /* DECLARE THE COUNTER ON OPTIONS ARRAY */
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

$counter=$counter+1; /* ADD 1 EVERY LOOP ON COUNTER */
}

echo "<input type='hidden' name='hiddencounter' value='$counter'>"; /* COUNT ALL THE LOOP AND SUBMIT IT TO THE NEXT FORM */

echo "<input name='userinvestoptionsdynamic' type='submit' value='Invest!'>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

**userinvestdynamic.php:**

```
<?php
require ('db_login.php'); 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['userinvestoptionsdynamic'])) {

$userid = $_SESSION['login_user']; /* I ASSUME YOU HAVE LOGIN_USER SESSION DECLARED IN THE PREVIOUS FILE? */
$companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
$options = $_POST['options'];
$counter = $_POST['hiddencounter']; /* THIS WILL SET AS YOUR COUNTER */

for ($i=0; $i<=$counter; $i++)
{

if(empty($options[$i])){ /* IF NO INPUT ON OPTIONS */
/* DO NOTHING */
}

else {

/* store single company and options in local variables */          

$query = "INSERT INTO user_company_invested(user_id, company_id, user_company_options_invested)
VALUES($userid,$companyid[$i],$options[$i])";

mysqli_query($connection, $query);

} /* END OF ELSE IF NOT EMPTY COMPANY ID */

} /* END OF FOR LOOP */

header('Location: userpage.php');

} /* END OF ISSET USERINVESTOPTIONSDYNAMIC */

else {
   echo 'Error!';
}

?>
```

Comment: Also, Logan, one thing that I realized was that I had primary keys set up incorrectly, so it was not allowing duplicate entries (which it should allow) --- not sure if that was part of the problem but your answer definitely helped to at least simplify and clean up my code.  Thanks again.

Comment: Its in your user_company_invested table, right? Try adding another field, and store it in their instead of storing it in your primary key field. Because the primary keys, (if Auto Increment), will generate a unique number for that field.

Comment: i actually don't have an auto increment field, i had 3 fields, a user_id, company_id, and options --- it is a many to many relationship with the same user able to allocate to multiple companies, and companies can be allocated by multiple users.  so i changed to not have any primary keys which is working well.

Comment: So its settle now? Okay then. Good luck with your work!